# Is there an equivalent to WinAPI's MAX_PATH under linux/unix?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, posix

If I want to allocate a char array (in C) that is guaranteed to be large enough to hold any valid absolute path+filename, how big does it need to be.

On Win32, there is the MAX_PATH define. What is the equivalent for Unix/linux?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is a `PATH_MAX`, but it is a bit problematic. From the bugs section of the [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) man page:

> The POSIX.1-2001 standard version of this function is broken by
>   design, since it is impossible to determine a suitable size for the
>   output buffer, *resolved_path*. According to POSIX.1-2001 a buffer of
>   size **PATH_MAX** suffices, but **PATH_MAX** need not be a defined
>   constant, and may have to be obtained using [pathconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pathconf.3.html). And
>   asking [pathconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pathconf.3.html) does not really help, since, on the one hand
>   POSIX warns that the result of [pathconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pathconf.3.html) may be huge and
>   unsuitable for mallocing memory, and on the other hand
>   [pathconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pathconf.3.html) may return -1 to signify that **PATH_MAX**is not
>   bounded.

Comment: However, since POSIX.1-2008 you can pass `NULL` to realpath(3) and it allocates an appropriate buffer by itself. So while it is still problematic to blindly trust `PATH_MAX` most of this answer does not apply anymore.

Answer (score 50):

The other answers so far all seem right on point about the *nix side of things, but I'll add a warning about it on Windows.

You've been lied to (by omission) by the documentation.

`MAX_PATH` is indeed defined, and probably even applies to files stored on FAT or FAT32. However, any path name can be prefixed by `\\?\` to tell the Windows API to ignore `MAX_PATH` and let the file system driver make up its own mind. After that, the definitions get fuzzy.

Add to the mix the fact that path names are actually Unicode (well, UTS-16) and that when the "ANSI" API is used the conversion to and from the internal Unicode name is dependent on a bunch of factors including the current code page, and you have a recipe for confusion.

A good description of the rules for Windows is at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx). The rules are much more complicated than I've summarized here.

**Edit:** I changed `\\.\` to `\\?\` in the above thanks to the comment from KitsuneYMG.

Windows paths and namespaces are complicated. Some might even argue they are too complicated. One source of complexity is that the Win32 (and now Win64) API is a subsystem that lays on top of the Windows NT native system.

A path without any prefix is compatible across the widest range of Windows platforms. If it is restricted to 7-bit ASCII characters, then it is compatible with 16-bit DOS since version 2.0 or so (whenever subdirectories were introduced, which might actually have been in DOS 3; but DOS 1.0 only had root directories and the `\` character had no special meaning).

The `\\?\` prefix causes the balance of the path name to be passed on verbatim to the appropriate file system driver, which is what produces the effect of dropping the restriction to `MAX_PATH` characters. If the long path name is also on a network share, then you can use an extended UNC name for it with the prefix `\\?\UNC\server\share\` instead of the normal UNC name `\\server\share\`.  Using this prefix restricts portability to Win32 and later Windows platforms, but unless you require support for 16-bit Windows on legacy hardware, that isn't a big issue.

The `\\.\` prefix is a different animal. It allows access to device objects beyond the set of specially named devices that are automatically mapped by Windows as special file names into every file folder. Those special names include CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Note that all of those names are special whether or not an extension is used, or in any mix of upper or lower case. But it is possible that you have 10 or more COM ports installed. This happens quickly if you play with USB modems, or USB serial port adapters, since each unique USB-based serial port will be assigned a distinct COMn name. If you need to access the 50th serial port, then you can only do so with the name `\\.\COM50` because COM50 is *not* a special name like COM1 is.

The MSDN page I cited above had the distinction right, I simply typed the incorrect prefix in my original answer.

Comment: Pretty sure you mean ` \\?\ `

Comment: @KitsuneYMG, right. I cited the wrong prefix. Its fixed now, along with a digression about what the distinction is.

Comment: \\.\ is not the prefix for named pipes ?

Comment: @v.oddou It is the prefix for named pipes because named pipes are Win32 Device Objects from the point of view of the kernel, and reside in the device object name space, accessed from User mode with the prefix \\.\

Comment: *`COM1` is special but `COM50` isn't* - yet another case of stupid MS design.

Comment: @rr- at the time they did that, compatibility was a *very* important mandate from their big value customers. So yes it was an unfortunate decision, but it was also one that was mandated by the commercial environment which paid the bills.

Comment: you can use `/` instead of `\\` pretty-much anywhere except on the command-line

Comment: @Jasen incorrect. You can use `start path/to/my/file` on command line without problem, but you can get into trouble if you paste a path with forward slash into many GUI applications

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc so long as `path` doesn't start with a slash or contain any spaces, you can...

Comment: Just walking by to say that holy jesus programming in C can get hairy... I miss the cozy world of Python and Java :\

Answer (score 24):

Well, on Linux at least, there is:

- `PATH_MAX` (defined in `limits.h`)
- `FILENAME_MAX` (defined in `stdio.h`)

both of these are set to `4096` on my system (x86 Linux).

**Update:** : [Some info from the glibc manual on this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Limits-for-Files)

> Each of the following macros is defined in limits.h only if the system has a fixed, uniform limit for the parameter in question. If the system allows different file systems or files to have different limits, then the macro is undefined; use pathconf or fpathconf to find out the limit that applies to a particular file

Comment: That looks like a portability no-no.

Comment: I suppose the maximum could vary depending on the filesystem type you're using, which would imply a runtime check, not a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 6):

FILENAME_MAX is part of the ISO C standard, it works on UNIX and Windows.  However, the GNU C library documentation contains the following warnings:

"Unlike PATH_MAX, this macro is defined even if there is no actual limit imposed. In such a case, its value is typically a very large number. This is always the case on the GNU system.

Usage Note: Don't use FILENAME_MAX as the size of an array in which to store a file name! You can't possibly make an array that big! Use dynamic allocation."

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pathconf()` to figure out at run-time, but there's also a PATH_MAX preprocessor define in `<limits.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `realpath` function to allocate a buffer big enough for a specific path. If you pass it a null pointer as the 2nd argument it will allocate a buffer big enough for the path. The man page probably explains it better than I can:

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to /./, /../ and extra '/' characters in the null-terminated string named by path to produce a canonicalized absolute pathname. The resulting pathname is stored as a null-terminated string, up to a maximum of PATH_MAX bytes, in the buffer pointed to by resolved_path. The resulting path will have no symbolic link, /./ or /../ components.
>
> **If resolved_path is specified as NULL, then realpath() uses malloc(3) to allocate a buffer of up to PATH_MAX bytes to hold the resolved pathname, and returns a pointer to this buffer. The caller should deallocate this buffer using free(3).**

http://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath

Answer (score 1):

limits.h

```
/*
 * File system limits
 *
 * NOTE: Apparently the actual size of PATH_MAX is 260, but a space is
 *       required for the NUL. TODO: Test?
 * NOTE: PATH_MAX is the POSIX equivalent for Microsoft's MAX_PATH; the two
 *       are semantically identical, with a limit of 259 characters for the
 *       path name, plus one for a terminating NUL, for a total of 260.
 */
#define PATH_MAX    260
```

minwindef.h

```
#define MAX_PATH 260
```