# What is a cross-platform way to get the current directory?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, getcwd

I need a cross-platform way to get the current working directory (yes, getcwd does what I want). I thought this might do the trick:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <direct.h>
    #define getcwd _getcwd // stupid MSFT "deprecation" warning
#elif
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s_cwd(getcwd(NULL,0));
    cout << "CWD is: " << s_cwd << endl;
}
```

I got this reading:

- [`_getcwd` at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getcwd-wgetcwd)
- [`getcwd` at Kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getcwd.3.html)
- [`getcwd` at Apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getcwd.3.html)

There should be no memory leaks, and it should work on a Mac as well, correct?

UPDATE: I fear something is still wrong here (I'm trying to avoid creating a char array with a determined length, as there's no proper way to get a decent length for getcwd):

```
char* a_cwd = getcwd(NULL,0);
string s_cwd(a_cwd);
free(a_cwd); // or delete a_cwd?
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If it is no problem for you to include, use [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) for convenient cross-platform filesystem operations.

```
boost::filesystem::path full_path( boost::filesystem::current_path() );
```

Here is an [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/example/simple_ls.cpp).

EDIT: as pointed out by Roi Danton in the comments, filesystem became part of the [ISO C++ in C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem), so boost is not needed anymore:

```
std::filesystem::current_path();
```

Comment: Should have mentioned: trying to limit external dependencies, so no Boost please.

Comment: ah, ok. I will leave this comment then in case other people stumble upon this question ;)

Comment: Beginning with C++14/C++17, you can use `std::filesystem::current_path()`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path

Comment: Why is it that when calling std::filesystem::current_path() from debugging in visual studio, I get the source files directory instead of the exe's output directory?

Comment: What `#include` is needed here?

Answer (score 14):

You cannot call `getcwd` with a NULL buffer.  As per the [Opengroup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html):

> If buf is a null pointer, the behavior of getcwd() is unspecified.

Also, getcwd can return NULL which can break a string constructor.

You'll need to change that to something like:

```
char buffer[SIZE];
char *answer = getcwd(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
string s_cwd;
if (answer)
{
    s_cwd = answer;
}
```

Comment: If he's "only" interested in compatibility with Windows, Linux, and Max OS X, then `getcwd(NULL)` is well defined. They all extend the function the same way.

Comment: I accepted this, but the above comment is imho correct. My code did have a memory leak though, so that needs solving

Comment: @RobKennedy - for Linux, it depends on the version being targeted.  For example, on a RHEL5 box, the `getcwd(NULL)` is still documented as being undefined.

Comment: Good luck using this on Windows with Unicode characters in the path.

Answer (score 3):

Calling [getcwd](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) with a NULL pointer is implementation defined.  It often does the allocation for you with malloc (in which case your code does have a memory leak).  However, it isn't guaranteed to work at all.  So you should allocate your own buffer.

```
char *cwd_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * max_path_len);
char *cwd_result = getcwd(cwd_buffer, max_path_len);
```

The Open Group has an example showing how to get the max path length from _PC_PATH_MAX.  You could consider using [MAX_PATH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833291/is-there-an-equivalent-to-winapis-max-path-under-linux-unix) for caveats to this number on both platforms.

Comment: Won't the std::string constructor free the malloc'ed memory?

Comment: @rubenvb, no, it just initializes the string to a copy.  It has no way of knowing how the passed in `char *` was allocated.