# How do I find the current directory?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, working-directory

I am trying to read a file which I read previously successfully.
I am reading it through a library, and I am sending it as-is to the library (i.e. "myfile.txt").
I know that the file is read from the working/current directory.

I suspect that the current/working directory has changed somehow.
How do i check what is the current/working directory?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you added the visual-c++ tag I'm going to suggest the standard windows function to do it. [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx)

Usage:

```
TCHAR pwd[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,pwd);
MessageBox(NULL,pwd,pwd,0);
```

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure it doesn't just write the part that fits in the buffer?

Comment: Really sorry... My program was incorrect..  I just deleted my comments so they wouldn't mislead others.  I tested it again: If the buffer size specified is not large enough, the buffer will be kept unmodified and the desired size will be returned.

Comment: Remember to add `#include <Windows.h>` to code file before this call.

Answer (score 8):

[Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html) library provides a clean solution

```
current_path()
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`_getcwd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y(VS.80).aspx) to get the current working directory.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the most platform-agnostic answer I got a while ago:

[How return a std::string from C's "getcwd" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869594/how-return-a-stdstring-from-cs-getcwd-function/2869667#2869667)

It's pretty long-winded, but does exactly what it's supposed to do, with a nice C++ interface (ie it returns a string, not a how-long-are-you-exactly?-(`const`) `char*`).

To shut up MSVC warnings about deprecation of `getcwd`, you can do a

```
#if _WIN32
    #define getcwd _getcwd
#endif // _WIN32
```

Answer (score 4):

This code works for Linux and Windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // defines FILENAME_MAX
#include <unistd.h> // for getcwd()
#include <iostream>

std::string GetCurrentWorkingDir();

int main()
{
   std::string str = GetCurrentWorkingDir();
   std::cout << str;
   return 0;
}
std::string GetCurrentWorkingDir()
{
    std::string cwd("\0",FILENAME_MAX+1);
    return getcwd(&cwd[0],cwd.capacity());
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Error:  E1696 cannot open source file "unistd.h". The unistd.h file is not part of C or C++ (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/59238/)

Comment: Only works if you are using gcc.  Does not work if you are using visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Since `C++17`, `std::filesystem::current_path()` can be used.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75354649/760728