# How do I keep my screenshot-making console program from blocking the screenshot?

Tags: c++, console-application, screenshot, windows-console

I have [code to make a screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3291411/1433767), but here is what my program produces:

[screenshot with control program blocking some of the screen http://imageshack.us/a/img27/7387/71240043.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img27/7387/71240043.png)

My program's console pops up and gets in the way. This is a split-second pop-up as the program takes the screen shot the split-second you double-click it.

I did some searching for information for how to hide it, and found [a forum with the following recommendation](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=9802.0):

> change the application type from "console" to "GUI application" in the target options (project properties -> tab "build targets").

But setting it to GUI application didn't get rid of the split-second console.

I tried looking for code to hide the console with, and found [an example](http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/topic/26476-c-how-to-hide-console-window/):

```
HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );
```

However, writing code to hide the console still has the console pop up and block the screenshot in the split second it appears.

What can I do to stop the console from appearing in that split second? I'm not bothered if the console is simply minimised, so long as it doesn't block the shot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think just switching the type is enough, since you need to change the entry point form `main` to `WinMain` too. Look at this example of how to make a windowless application ( http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/82f506c4-ac1f-48c1-a5dc-51bfe99cf850 ), I'd suggest making a new Win32 project and then copying over the code you have.

Comment: Where would I get the current working directory from in API instance?

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with the question at hand, @User. You can use Google for that, or even [Stack Overflow's own search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+current+working+directory+API). It would show you a previous question here: [How do I find the current directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4807629/33732)

Answer (score 1):

Using Rudolf's suggestion, I did the research and can answer the question specifically:

Change `int main()` to `int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)`. (Correction) This will only work if the settings are graphical.

And to deal with the issue of not having access to `int main`'s `argc`/`argv` options, use `__argc` and `__argv`, which is an external variable found in `stdlib.h`.

See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126571

Answer (score 1):

Hacky, but... after hiding the window you can delay long enough for that to take effect on-screen. Here I use C++11 (`#include <thread>` for this_thread and `#include <chrono>` for milliseconds) so you'd need to use VS2012 to use this exact code to delay.

```
HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
if (!console)
    ; // handle error
BOOL was_visible = ShowWindow(console, SW_HIDE);

// delay for a fraction of a second...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));

// ... take screen shot

if (was_visible)
    ShowWindow(console, SW_SHOW);
```