# fopen with a .app file

Tags: c++, qt, fopen, executable-path

I am working on a Qt project which maps vowels onto a chart that have the *.sym format.

My goal is to load an initial IPA chart like [this](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~krussll/138/sec5/vow-ipa.gif).

I have the `*.sym` files and I can load them after my application starts, but I'm not really sure where my executable is executing.

I have a directory format (after building) like this

```
Project
|_ Source
|_ Build
  |_ Source
    |_ Charts
      |_ load_at_start.sym
    |_ Project.app
      |_ Contents
        |_ MacOS
          |_ Project (executable)
```

This makes using an fopen call quite difficult. I assumed that fopen would consider the current working directory as the place where the executable rested, so I tried something like this...

```
    FILE *stream = fopen("./../../../charts/load_at_start.sym", "r");
```

but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your path is a relative path and so it relative to the working directory. Perhaps the working directory is not what you think it is. Did you check what it is?

Comment: try printing out your current directory when the exe starts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807629/how-do-i-find-the-current-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to make sure the .sym file ends up within the app bundle (the .app directory), specifically under Contents/Resources.

Then you can use [QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath) to obtain the directory of your application (e.g. "/Applications/Project.app/Contents/MacOS/") and append the relative path to your file (e.g. "../Resources/charts/load_at_start.sym").

Something like this:

```
QDir dir(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath());
dir.cd("../Resources/charts");
FILE* stream = fopen(dir.filePath("load_at_start.sym").toUtf8().constData());
```

Although you might want to consider using Qt's I/O facilities instead of C's.

Comment: This worked for me basically. I haven't tested it on the other platforms, though. I'll comment later after Linux test has been conducted. Thanks a lot!