# How do I find the directory path of a file I created from ofstream in C++?

Tags: c++, ofstream

I want to get the directory of a file which I created using ofstream.
Code I wrote is something like

```
std::ofstream txt("sample.txt", std::ios::binary);
```

Then I write some things to the txt file, then call txt.close() to close the ofstream. While writing, I want to get the location of the sample.txt file and write it on to sample.txt.
For example, the directory path would be like this:

```
/home/usr/Downloads/sample.txt
```

I want to save that whole thing as string so I can write it into sample.txt file. Can anyone help?
I am using linux to code this, and a universal way to do this would be nice(working on windows, linux, mac etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into [Boost.Filesystem](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/index.html) for portable path handling. C++ does't have too much for paths, as you might be running on platforms without a file system. However, you could try to get something with [getcwd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) and appending '/' between the output and your file name. getcwd is not part of C, but it's available on Windows as [_getcwd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y.aspx) -- POSIX compliant systems will have the canonical `getcwd`. This should work (but I'm pretty sure there are corner cases where it won't, for instance, if running from UNC paths or so.)

Answer (score 1):

Well on windows, I can give you a hand. Get Working Directory 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
 #include <direct.h>

 char cCurrentPath[MAX_PATH];
_getcwd(cCurrentPath,sizeof(cCurrentPath));
```

sounds like what you're looking for.

OH OH OH look here
[What is a cross-platform way to get the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868680/what-is-a-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-current-directory)

Comment: Is that first solution MC++? I haven't really been exposed to extended c++ libs, but I don't think that would be a plausible solution as I don't think he's using MS Tasks: ITask::GetWorkingDirectory()

Comment: How would I implement that in getting string of a path of a file?

Comment: cCurrentPath now holds the string of your current directory. Append it with the filename, and you've got it.