# Force program to use executable's directory for I/O instead of active directory non-programmatically

Tags: c++, c, windows, unix, io

If I have an executable: `project/bin/exec`, which caches data into a `file.txt` in its active directory, the location where `file.txt` will be saved depends on how I run the program:

- `project/file.txt` if I run it from `project` with `bin/exec`
- `project/bin/file.txt` if I run it from `project/bin` with `./exec`

I'd like the program to *always* use the directory of the executable and **I'd like to find out if there's a non-programatic way of forcing it to do it.**

**I'm interested in UNIX/Windows, does this even make sense?**

Programatically, I know I could get the executable's directory by using `boost` or `std::experimental` `filesystem`, perhaps `args[0]` argument and use that path for I/O.

**Is that the way to do it?**

Comment: The only way to use a fixed location is to use absolute paths.

Comment: That's been asked before. On Linux you can resolve `/proc/self/exe` to find your own location.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868680/what-is-a-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-current-directory

Comment: A non-programming solution is not a question for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing this on **Unix** (part of the question) would be to use a script which would chdir before running executable.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

loc=`dirname $0`
cd $loc
echo $PWD
```

Comment: That will not work on Windows.

Comment: @perencia, yeah, missed OP is interested in Windows solution as well. I am pretty sure similar techinque could be employed in Windows, however, I am not familiar with Microsoft products that well.

Comment: It's not completely clear in the question but I assume that a cross-platform is what is asked for. I posted as a comment a link to a related cross-platform question.

Comment: @perencia, I doubt you can do it both cross-platform and non-programmatically :)

Comment: that part of the question i do not understand. Isn't what you have done "programmatically" ? So, is non-programatically the same as "outside the main program" ? For non-programmatic i've always thought as "by-configuration", but leveraging the actual configuration :)

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks for the answer, meanwhile, I've decided. I'll do it programatically :) Cross-platform and less painful.