# How to use environment variables in bazel/googletest

Tags: c++, bash, g++, googletest, bazel

So I want to use Bazel and the GoogleTest framework for running unit tests of a simulation. For this, I want to have sample-inputfiles and sample-outputfiles.
I want to get the absolute path of the source file, the test file or any file in the repository, so I can create a relative path to input files from there.

E.g.:

```
std::string path = __SOME_PATH_IN_REPO__+"/../inputfiles/input.txt";
std::fstream infile(path);
```

So after a lot of searching, I found out that you can define constants straight from the BUILD file for bazel like so:

```
cc_test( 
    name = "gtest_capabilities", 
    srcs = [ 
        "testing/pwdTest.cpp", 
    ],          
    deps = [ 
        "@gtest//:main", 
    ],          
    copts = [ 
            "-D __ABSOLUTE_PATH__=$(workspace)", 
    ],          
)
```

The important line is in copts, where I am using `$(workspace)`.
I read [here](http://www.bazel.io/docs/be/c-cpp.html), that you can specify copts (or alternatively `defines`) like this, which does work.
[This](http://www.bazel.io/docs/be/make-variables.html#make-var-substitution) page, which the first page links to, tells me, I can use environment variables like this: *$(FOO)*
It also tells me, that I can run `bazel info --show_make_env` to get all availabe environment variables.

When I run it, I get a big list of environment variables, which contains workspace, next to alot of others.
**Now here comes the problem:**
But when I use the `$(workspace)` variable, bazel tells me, that $(workspace) is not defined.
I would also work for me if I could use the $PWD variable, but I couldn't get this to work either.

I hope someone can help me.
Greetings,
Romeo

Edit:
I now use the 'data' option in the bazel build file. This works mostly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, this is a terrible output.  Basically, `--show_make_env` mushes together the output of `bazel info` and the make variables, giving no indication of which is which.  To find the make variables, you can diff the outputs to remove the non-make info:

```
$ bazel info --show_make_env > make-vars
$ bazel info > no-make-vars
$ diff make-vars no-make-vars
1,22d0
< ABI: local
< ABI_GLIBC_VERSION: local
< ANDROID_CPU: armeabi
< AR: /usr/bin/ar
< BINDIR: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin
< BINMODE: -dbg
< CC: /usr/bin/gcc
< CC_FLAGS: 
< COMPILATION_MODE: fastbuild
< CROSSTOOLTOP: external/local_config_cc
< C_COMPILER: compiler
< GENDIR: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/genfiles
< GLIBC_VERSION: local
< JAVA: external/local_jdk/bin/java
< JAVABASE: external/local_jdk
< JAVA_CPU: k8
< JAVA_TRANSLATIONS: 0
< NM: /usr/bin/nm
< OBJCOPY: /usr/bin/objcopy
< STACK_FRAME_UNLIMITED: 
< STRIP: /usr/bin/strip
< TARGET_CPU: k8
```

Those are the make variables that are available.

Could you find the PWD in your test, instead of using a `-D` to hardcode it?

Comment: Yeah, it's my goal to get PWD in my code, but I've spend quite some time trying to figure out a cross-platform way and I didn't find a good one. Some people suggest using _ _FILE_ _ but it doesn't give me the full path.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868680/what-is-a-cross-platform-way-to-get-the-current-directory?