# How to dynamically allocate name array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having some problems with dynamic allocation, because I don't want to specify the size of the array. Basically what I need in my program is to store a name of a file in an array and make sure it is not wasting space.

I was trying to do something like creating the array `name[255]` to make sure it had enough space and then dynamically allocate it so it had only the required space, like writing "matrix5", then store it in `name[255]` and then change `name[255]` to `name[8]`.

```
char file_name[255];

printf("what is the name of the file? [.txt]\n");
scanf_s(" %s", file_name[255]); //store name eg: "matrix5"

i = 0;
char **fullpath;
while (file_name[i] != '\0' && i <=strlen(file_name))
{
    fullpath= (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));  //In here it would then make file_name[255] into file_name[8]                             
    fullpath[i] = file_name[i];
    i++;
}
```

What do I need to do here?

Comment: Post the code you used, sample input and expected output.

Comment: As always, `scanf_s()` isn't used correctly.

Comment: `scanf_s(" %s", file_name);` is missing a length argument.

Comment: thanks for the input, will be editing to correct this mistakes

Comment: Note that `scanf_s(" %s", file_name[255]);` is worse than before.  You need 3 arguments to `scanf_s()` in this context — you should have `if (scanf_s("%s", file_name, (unsigned)sizeof(file_name)) == 1) { …process file name… }`.  See [`scanf_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) for why the `unsigned` cast is needed.

Comment: Are you working on a RAM-restricted system with no virtual memory manager?  If not, just stick with [255].

Comment: true, it is easier to do that but since this is for college I am trying to do it with memory allocation since my professor asked. Maybe it would be easier to just ask the number of characters of the file_name, then do malloc and be done with it lol

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hmmm, MS with `scanf_s()` wants `unsigned` yet C11 Annex K wants `rsize_t/size_t`.  --> A sad state of affairs.

Comment: @chux: yes — see also [Do you use the TR 24731 'safe' functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions).

Answer (score 3):

File names and path names typically have a maximal length that the system can handle.  Example [MAX_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/833291/2410359).  Declare an array the hold user input.  IMO, I would use a 2x sized array for user input.

```
//                                +1 for \n
#define MY_BUFFER_SIZE (MAX_PATH*2 + 1)
char my_buffer[MY_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Read the file name

```
printf("what is the name of the file? [.txt]\n");
if (fgets(my_buffer, sizeof my_buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
  Handle_EnfOfFile_or_InputError();
  return NULL;
}
```

Lop off the potential trailing \n

```
my_buffer[strcspn(my_buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Create a duplicate

```
return strdup(my_buffer);
```

`strdup()` is not a stand C library function but easy enough to code.  [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39694254/2410359).

Answer (score 1):

That is how you would allocate a c-string dynamically:

```
char* name = malloc(sizeof(char)*(length+1)); //length of the filename plus \0
```

Comment: Curious, As `sizeof(char)` is always 1, why use `sizeof(char)*(length+1)` instead of `length+1` or `sizeof *name * (length+1)`?

Comment: I like consistency, so when needing the size of an int, you can just replace 'char' with 'int. And also when copying code modifications become easier.

Comment: I believe that was the point of the suggestion `sizeof *name` which is low-maintenance and can be a consistent coding style.

Comment: Of course this is personal preference, but I think my version is more readable.

Comment: @Shiro Consider reviewing someone else's code 1000s of lines of code which has a bug - somewhere. `data.str = malloc(sizeof *data.str * n)` versus `data.str = malloc(sizeof(some_type) * n)` with the member `str` type defined in some other `#include` file.  The first is more likely coded correctly, lower maintenance, easier to review than the 2nd which obligates a lookup in that distant `.h` file..  IMO, it is not a personal preference, but a group/company coding standard preference.  Still, thanks for you thoughts.

Comment: "I think my version is more readable" ... so you think `sizeof(char)*(length+1)` is "more readable" than `(sizeof *name) * (length + 1)`? Wow, that's clutching at straws... I mean, for the disputable *slight* gain in *readability* you have an indisputable *significant* loss in *maintainability*. Is the trade-off worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)?

This will return a pointer to an allocated memory (that will need to be free by you later) with a copy of the string, and makes the code much simpler.

Tip: use `strndup` if you are not copying constant strings.